# How to get document by current signed in user in Google Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get a specific document that is created when a user signs up. I made it so that when the use signs up, their firebase user ID is the name of the document.

I can't seem to figure out how to call that document.

I have tried: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
uid
userId (from computed)
and several other related things to the uid.

When I look for a solution online I see the exact examples I have tried and I am wondering if there has been a change to how uid works maybe?

```
<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line
import firebase from "firebase";
// eslint-disable-next-line
import firestore from "firestore";
import db from "@/components/fbInit";

export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    userId() {
      return firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    }
  },
  created() {
    db.collection("userProfiles")
       .document(userId)
       .get()
       .then(querySnapshot => {
         querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data().name,
            company: doc.data().company,
            state: doc.data().state
          };
          this.users.push(data);
         });
      });
  }
};
 </script>
```

Usually I get no error but it doesn't load any document. Sometimes it will say "uid" or whatever I am trying to use is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for anyone else wondering. unique is a field I set to match the user ID when a user is created. Alternatively I believe you can use author to get the author of the document.

```
var user =  firebase.auth().currentUser


db.collection("userProfiles").where('unique', '==', user.uid).get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => { }
```